# Issue with css floats over div's

Tags: html, css, css-float

i dont know why it always happens while am using floats

my div(samle) look like this

```
 <div class="main>
   <div class="inn_div">&nbsp</div>
 </div>
```

and my stylesheet

```
  .main{ width:250px; border:1px solid #000; }

  .main .inn_div{ float:left; width:25px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000; }
```

and its looks like this

[image: By this way it shows]

the inn_div comes out from .main moreover it works fine when am using "inline-block or table-cell" i don't need those wat's s problem with problem with float or by me guys help me.

Comment: Are you sure your markup is correct? `<div class="main>` & `&nbsp`

Comment: You need to clear the floated element, or set the parent to the same height as the floated element. Do a search on [CSS float tutorial](http://www.google.com/#q=css+float+tutorial).

Comment: yep,it looks like that markup only @SonuJoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your main div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E9nac/)**

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to clear float.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2cH/)

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="inn_div">
       &nbsp;
   </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Some time those clearfix also not works..Anyways those problems are by my mistakes thanks @Sonu Joshi

Answer (score 1):

your main div is acting as a wrapper div if you do not want them to overlap do not put the inner div inside of the main div. but if you must do it then you can mess around with margin-top property or padding-top property until you are content with the spacing

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CSS clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp). 
eg. clear:both

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to specify a height or minimim-height for the main class. You have only the width. No need for any other script like JavaScript.